# Spry Tabbed Panels JS core modification

Tags: javascript, tabs, widget, spry

I'm having trouble and I am not sure on how to tackle this problem.

I have a Spry Tabbed Panels Widget with content. I know that the 3-level, 5-container structure is essential for the Tabbed Panels widget to work properly, but I would like to add one more level (the container class below the main div), like this:

```
<div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">
    <div class="content">
        <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
            <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Home</li>
            <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Profile/li>
            <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Contact</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
            <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">Content 1</div>
            <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">Content 2</div>
            <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">Content 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As far as I understand, in order to get this to work properly, I would have to modify the widget core. Can anyone point me in the right direction or help me modify the widget core?
Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">
```

would work as

```
<div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels content">
```

so there is no need for another div layer...